# Update the views, after updating a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, viewmodel

I have created a model with Name, Email, Phone no properties and also created views for create, edit, delete and index. All these are working fine.

Now I have added a property in model like Address. Now I want that, is there any method so that, after adding the property in model, the newly added property automatic add in all the respective views.

Can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way but only applicable if the view is generated by using HTML helper classes. The view should be strongly typed.

```
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

This HTML helper will automatically update and genatrate required input fields but with this you might have limited flexibility.

Other way can be creating your own class that renders html page.

Use as below in your view. View should be strongly typed of the model you want to use:

```
@using(html.BeginForm()){
    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this tag in view and how the changes will reflect in views after updating the model?

Comment: I have added the tag as you provided in the view and then added a property in model and build the project. But the added property will not come automatically in view.
How the property will come automatically in view?

Comment: can you share some more details of your implementation. I have done this and it worked for me